# C++ SFML collision detection between different classes

Tags: c++, class, collision, sfml, detection

I am making a C++ SFML version of Frogger and currently trying to implement collision detection between the frog and other objects (cars, trucks, logs etc). I have separate classes for the frog and the game objects and want to use bounding boxes to detect intersections as shown below.

```
// get the bounding box of the entity
sf::FloatRect boundingBox = entity.getGlobalBounds();
// check collision with another box (like the bounding box of another 
entity)
sf::FloatRect otherBox = ...;
if (boundingBox.intersects(otherBox))
{
    // collision!
}
```

The problem I am having is that I have no idea how to make this work with two sprites from separate classes and after days of searching I can't find an explanation of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are two objects 'a' and 'b' that contain the sprites that you want to test for.
Then you can call the following in your code to test for a collision between them:

```
#include "MyEntityA.hpp"
#include "MyEntityB.hpp"

MyEntityA entity_a;
MyEntityB entity_b;   

if(entity_a.getSprite().getGlobalBounds().intersects(entity_b.getSprite().getGlobalBounds()))
{
    // A collision happened.
}
```

Look here for further information: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/graphics-transform.php#bounding-boxes

Comment: The problem that I am having is that the two sprites are from separate header and cpp files so when I try to do this one of the sprites is undefined.  

My frogSprite is in my frog.cpp and other game objects such as the cars are in my game.cpp. The problem is that I have no idea how to check for collision as they are not in the same part of my code.

Comment: I think the problem that you have is not specific to sfml but to programming in C++ in general. If you have for example your Game.hpp, you include "ClassA.hpp" and "ClassB.hpp" in there, then you create objects of those classes and with these objects you test the collision. Does that help?

Comment: That explanation makes sense i'll have a go at fixing it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to forward declare your classes in order to make each other see each other.

**carsprite.h**

```
class FrogSprite; //declare your FrogSprite here

class CarSprite
{

};
```

**frogsprite.h**

```
class CarSprite;

class FrogSprite
{

};
```

after that, you can include the header files in its cpp files to see the classes's full definition.

**carsprite.cpp**

```
#include "frogsprite.h"
```

**frogsprite.cpp**

```
#include "carsprite.ccp"
```